# Como inicializar un constructor que pide como parámetro un objeto

Tags: java, herencia, polimorfismo

Estoy realizando un programa para practicar el tema de herencia y polimorfismo. Este consta de cuatro principales clases en primera instancia a la clase Empleado(base para las demás) seguidamente de Secretario, Vendedor y Jefe de zona. Cada una de ellas con sus atributos y métodos heredando en su mayoría los datos de la clase principal (Empleado). El problema es que no sé como inicializar el constructor cuando en el parámetro se me pide que ponga un objeto.

Clase base

```
package taller.relaciones.de.clases.parte.pkg2;

/**
 *
 * @author Usuario
 */
public class Empleado {
    
    // atributos
    
    String nombre; 
    String apellidos;
    int DNI;
    String direccion; 
    int años_antiguedad;
    int telefono;
    double salario;
    Empleado supervisor;
    
    // metodos
    
    Empleado(String nombre, String apellidos, int DNI, String direccion, int años_antiguedad, int telefono, double salario, Empleado supervisor){
        this.nombre=nombre;
        this.apellidos=apellidos;
        this.DNI=DNI;
        this.direccion=direccion;
        this.años_antiguedad=años_antiguedad;
        this.telefono=telefono;
        this.salario=salario;
        this.supervisor=supervisor;
    }
    
    public void Imprimir(){
        System.out.println("Nombre: "+ nombre + "\n" +
                "Apellidos: "+ apellidos + "\n" +
                "DNI: "+ DNI + "\n" +
                "Direccion: "+ direccion + "\n" +
                "Años de antiguedad: "+ años_antiguedad + "\n" +
                "Telefono: "+ telefono + "\n" +
                "Salario: "+ salario + "\n" +
                "Supervisor: "+ supervisor + "\n");
    }
    
    public void cambiarSupervisor(Empleado nuevoSupervisor){
        
        this.supervisor=nuevoSupervisor;
    }
    
    public void incrementar(double incremento){
        this.salario=salario+incremento*salario;
        System.out.println("El salario sumandole el incremento es de: " + salario);
    }
}
```

Clase hija

```
package taller.relaciones.de.clases.parte.pkg2;

/**
 *
 * @author Usuario
 */
public class Secretario extends Empleado {
    String despacho;
    int fax;

    public Secretario(String despacho, int fax, String nombre, String apellidos, int DNI, String direccion, int años_antiguedad, int telefono, double salario, Empleado supervisor) {
        super(nombre, apellidos, DNI, direccion, años_antiguedad, telefono, salario, supervisor);
        this.despacho = despacho;
        this.fax = fax;
    }
    @Override
    public void Imprimir(){
        System.out.println("Despacho: "+ despacho + "\n" +
                           "Fax: " + fax +"/n");
    }
    
}
```

Clase main

```
package taller.relaciones.de.clases.parte.pkg2;

/**
 *
 * @author Usuario
 */
public class TallerRelacionesDeClasesParte2 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Secretario secretario1 = new Secretario("Oficina 34",56897513,"Andres","Moreno",1005712016,"Calle 58 norte# 2FN59",5,3214360275,3500000,);
    }
    
}
```

Me gustaría aclarar que en la clase main, en la ultima coma "," que esta al lado del paréntesis debe ir el objeto que les menciono pero no se como llenar ese campo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El constructor de `Secretario` espera como último parámetro un objeto del tipo `Empleado`, entonces tienes que crear una instancia de esa clase y pasarla como parámetro.

Por ejemplo:

```
Empleado supervisorOne=new Empleado("Pedro","",1,"",1,1,1,null);
Secretario secretario1 = new Secretario("Oficina 34",56897513,"Andres","Moreno",1005712016,"Calle 58 norte# 2FN59",5,32,3500000,supervisorOne);
```

He cambiado algunos valores, porque son demasiado grandes para ser del tipo `int`.

También, tus métodos de mostrar datos son poco prácticos. En `Secretario`, deberías llamar al método de la clase padre, para mostrar el resto de datos. Y, siempre es mejor devolver una cadena, y mostrarla en el contexto, no tienes por qué imprimir desde una clase que pertenece al modelo de datos.

He agregado un método `getName()`  a `Empleado`, para mostrar también el nombre del supervisor, cabe decir que deberías agregar todos los *getter* que faltan a las clase.

Los métodos de que hablo más arriba quedarían así:

**En la clase `Empleado`**:

```
public String Imprimir(){
    return String.format("Nombre: %s%n Apellidos: %s%n DNI: %d%n Direccion: %s%n Años de antiguedad: %d%n Telefono: %d%n Salario: %f%n Supervisor: %s%n",
                         nombre,
                         apellidos,
                         DNI,
                         direccion,
                         años_antiguedad,
                         telefono,
                         salario,
                         supervisor.getName());
}
```

Y también este método:

```
public String getName() {
    return this.nombre;
}
```

**En la clase `Secretario`:**

```
@Override
public String Imprimir(){
    return String.format("%s%nDespacho: %s%nFax: %s%n",super.Imprimir(),despacho,fax);
}
```

La salida ahora se verá así:

```
Nombre: Andres
 Apellidos: Moreno
 DNI: 1005712016
 Direccion: Calle 58 norte# 2FN59
 Años de antiguedad: 5
 Telefono: 32
 Salario: 3500000.000000
 Supervisor: Pedro

Despacho: Oficina 34
Fax: 56897513
```

Cabe decir que, por convención de nombre, los métodos `Imprimir` deberían llamarse `toString()`, pues esa es su funcionalidad, monstrar una representación del objeto como cadena.

Te dejo un demo completo del código:

**[`VER DEMO EN REXTESTER`](https://rextester.com/DFO57082)**